# Unit Test Results from 'dotnet test' call in Docker

Tags: docker, .net-core, azure-devops, teamcity

I am starting to investigate Azure Devops and its pipelines feature for setting up a continuous integration workflow. I have a pipeline that builds a Docker image of my application using the following dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build-env

WORKDIR /cicd

# restore (put more volatile, changing projects later in process)
COPY src/WebApp/WebApp.csproj ./src/WebApp/
RUN dotnet restore src/WebApp/WebApp.csproj -s http://mycontainerrepo.acme.com/repository/nuget/

COPY tests/WebApp.Test/WebApp.Test.csproj ./tests/WebApp.Test/
RUN dotnet restore tests/WebApp.Test/WebApp.Test.csproj -s http://mycontainerrepo.acme.com/repository/nuget/

# copy source
COPY . .

# test (if tests fail, no final image, yay)
RUN dotnet test tests/WebApp.Test/WebApp.Test.csproj

# publish
RUN dotnet publish src/WebApp/WebApp.csproj -o /publish

# runtime stage
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim AS release
COPY --from=build-env /publish /publish
WORKDIR /publish
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApp.dll"]
```

The call to run `dotnet test` executes just fine and outputs results to the console, but I don't know of any way to make use of this result in the pipeline. In TeamCity, you could set an [environment variable](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/1590) to sort of trick it into outputting the test results (xUnit only, I think...). But not sure if there's a similar trick here...

I saw [this post](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/master/samples/dotnetapp/dotnet-docker-unit-testing.md) on Github about making a separate test image just for testing but was hoping to avoid that route unless its my only option.

Any other CI/CD Azure Devops gurus out there?

Comment: Can you run the docker compose to build the containers?

Comment: I can for sure, but just haven’t created a compose file yet. How would that help?

Comment: In the compose you can mount a volume to the agent and put the test results there.

Comment: That's still an issue with TeamCity - no support for (nunit) tests with multi-stage docker builds. Neither TEAMCITY_PROJECT_NAME, nor trx logger help.

Comment: Good to know, thanks!